# passing state from one component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

So I tried to make a login system in react laravel mix and god.... it's so hard. Now i've got an idea to make the right logic which needs me to pass a state from one component to another. In this case, I tried to pass a state from login.js to master.js component.

The state i tried to pass was `isLogged`

Login.js code

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {userEmail: '', userPassword:'', isLogged: false, isLoggedfail: false, dataUser:{}};

    this.handleChange1 = this.handleChange1.bind(this);
    this.handleChange2 = this.handleChange2.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange1(e){
    this.setState({
      userEmail: e.target.value
    })
  }
  handleChange2(e){
    this.setState({
      userPassword: e.target.value
    })
  }
  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const usern = {

      email: this.state.userEmail,
      password: this.state.userPassword

    }
    let uri = 'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login';
    axios.post(uri, usern).then(response => {
          this.setState({ isLogged: true });
          this.setState({dataUser: response.data.data}) 
          sessionStorage.setItem("key", this.state.dataUser.id_user)
          console.log(this.state.dataUser.id_user)
          this.props.history.push('/');
        }
    ).catch(error => {
  console.log("Error:" + error.message)
  this.setState({isLoggedfail: true})
})
  }
```

and master.js

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {cari: '', diCari:false, isLoggedIn:false};

    this.handleChange1 = this.handleChange1.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange1(e){
    this.setState({
      cari: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit(e){
          this.setState({ diCari: false });
  console.log("makan")
  const cari = {
    cari: this.state.cari
    }

      this.setState({ diCari: true });
      this.props.history.push("/search/"+this.state.cari) 
    }
  componentDidMount(){
  if(sessionStorage.getItem("key") !== null)  {
    this.setState({Logged:true})
    }
    else{
      this.setState({Logged:false})
    }
  }

    componentDidUpdate(props){
      if(this.state.logout){
        this.setState({logout:false})
        this.props.history.push('/')
      }
      else if(this.state.Logged){
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("key") !== null)  {
       this.setState({Logged:false})
      }
    }
}
```

Route:

```
render(){
    return(
      <HashRouter>

  <div className="wrap">
  <Master/>
  <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
    <Route exact path="/search/:userId" component={Search} />
    <Route exact path="/carts/:userId" component={Keranjang} />
    <Route exact path="/produk/:userId" component={Product} />
    </Switch>
    </div>
      <Footer/>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}
}
if (document.getElementById('app')) {
        ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('app'));
      }
```

Please note, I tried to use the `isLogged` state at `componentDidupdate` but right now I am using session check which is causing an infinite loop.

Thank you so much for your help! I've been stuck for 3 days making the auth in react.

Comment: Can you please share your routes?

Comment: @tareqaziz done brother

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see what you have in your render functions?
To share state, it's better to use callBack functions and send data back up the hierarchy.

Also in your promise.then
you are setting state and then doing a history.push
which doesn't make sense:
 - Because you will lose local state if you are directed off the page (unmount)

Also it would be a good idea to name your functions better than handleChange1 handleChange2

Comment: my render functions at master.js still blank, i plan to use it after i understand how to pass the state

Comment: should i use redirect instead of history.push?